# Why does Matlab's `bitxor(1000,10)` gives 994?

Tags: matlab, xor

I know that `bitxor` is bit by bit addition modulo 2, so isn't `bitxor(1000,10)` supposed to give 1010? why is it giving me 994?

Comment: Because of that "modulo 2" part in the 4th bit... `1111101000 xor 0000001010 = 1111100010`.

Comment: @beaker, how do I get it to give me '1010'? is there another function?

Comment: I spoke too quickly... only addition will give you 1010 decimal. Bitwise operators will not give you the carry you need in this case. This assumes that `1000` and `10` are meant to be decimal values, not binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is 1000 and 10 are NOT binary numbers.
In decimal 0b1000 would be 8 and 0b10 would be 2.
Try this:

```
bitxor(8,2)
ans = 10
```

Now you might think its wrong but ans is also NOT binary, its decimal 10 which equals 1010 binary.

EDIT: to make it work the way you want try this:

```
dec2bin(bitxor(bin2dec('1000'), bin2dec('10'))
ans = 1010
```

Comment: That's a good point, I hadn't even considered that the OP meant the inputs to be binary.